# ¿Como validar un input en AngularJS (Angular 1) para que no muestre error en los otros si se muestran con un ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs

tengo el siguiente html para poder agregar teléfonos a un contacto,hago una validación con AngularJS para que no se registren teléfonos con caracteres si no solo números, el problema es que si agrego dos telefonos el primero correctamente y el segundo incorrecto, me manda el mensaje de error en ambos, no se si se pueda evitar eso con la estructura que tengo.

```
        <div class="input-group select-phone" ng-repeat="tel in contacto.director.telefonos">
            <select name="otroTipoTel-director" ng-model="tel.tipotel" class="input_director" id="" ng-disabled="inputDirector">
                  <option value="">--Selecciona</option>
                  <option value="Asistente">Tel. Asistente</option>
                  <option value="Personal">Tel. Personal</option>
                  <option value="Fax">Tel. FAX</option>
                  <option value="Personal2">Tel. Personal 2</option>
                  <option value="Oficina">Tel. Oficina 2</option>
            </select>
            <!-- número de teléfono-->
            <input maxlength="12" id="otroTel-director" type="text" ng-disabled="inputDirector" class="input_director" ng-model="tel.telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" name="otroTelDir" mask="99-9999-9999" ng-pattern="/^\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{4}$/" ng-class="{invalid: formContactoDependencia.otroTelDir.$error.pattern}">
            <!-- extension del teléfono-->
            <input maxlength="80" id="otroExt-director" type="text" ng-disabled="inputDirector" class="input_director extension" ng-model="tel.extension" placeholder="Extensión" name="otroExtDir" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" ng-class="{invalid: formContactoDependencia.extDirector.$error.pattern}">
            <!-- boton X para eliminar-->
            <a href="#" id="telDirector" class="dropIt Alagoma" ng-show="Xdirector" ng-click="quitarNuevo(contacto, contacto.director.telefonos.indexOf(t), $event)">X</a>
            <div ng-show="formContactoDependencia.otroTelDir.$error.pattern">
                <span class="error" >
                    El número de telefono no cumple con el formato correcto 
                </span>
            </div> 
            <div ng-show="formContactoDependencia.otroExtDir.$error.pattern">
                <span class="error" >
                     Introduce solo numeros en la extensión
                </span>
            </div> 
       </div>
```

Tengo el siguiente boton para agregar un nuevo telefono...

```
         <div class="adiciona Alagoma" ng-show="Adirector" id="directorTelefono" ng-click="nuevoTelefono(telefonoDirector,contacto , $event)" ng-hide="contacto.director.telefonos.length>=4"> <!-- ng-hide="dess" -->
            <div><i class="icon director-telefono" ></i></div>
                <span>Agregar</span>
        </div>
```

El cual solo crea un nuevo espacio en el arreglo contacto.director.telefonos
el scope que lo hace es el siguiente...

```
    //Scope para agregar un nuevo telefono
    $scope.nuevoTelefono = function (obj,contacto, e) {
        var e = e.target.id;
        console.log(e, "es el valor de ...")
        if(e == "directorTelefono") {
                console.log('Contacto --> ' + JSON.stringify(contacto));
                if(contacto.director){
                    if(contacto.director.telefonos){

                        if($.isArray(contacto.director.telefonos)){
                            if (contacto.director.telefonos.length < 4) contacto.director.telefonos.push({});
                        }else{
                            $scope.contacto.director.telefonos = [];
                            if (contacto.director.telefonos.length < 4) contacto.director.telefonos.push({});
                        }

                    }else{
                        contacto.director.telefonos = [];
                            if (contacto.director.telefonos.length < 4) contacto.director.telefonos.push({});
                    }
                }else{
                    contacto.director = "sdfsdfsd";
                    console.log(contacto.director)
                    contacto.director.telefonos = [];
                            if (contacto.director.telefonos.length < 4) contacto.director.telefonos.push({});
                }
        }
    };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: consulta, como agregas un segundo telefono? es un input que ya esta hecho, que viene por defecto en un objeto? es dinamico?

Comment: es un input hecho, viene en el código de arriba, creo que el problema es que al hacer un recorrido, los dos imputs tienen el mismo atributo name, por eso hace la validacion en ambas.

Comment: te deje la respuesta @AlbertoRojas

Comment: ng-pattern="/^\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{4}$/" este es para la etiqueta input y este es el encargado de mostrar el mensaje  *<div ng-show="formContactoDependencia.otroTelDir.$error.pattern">
                <span class="error" >
                    El número de telefono no cumple con el formato correcto 
                </span>
            </div>* pero veo que mi error esta en que lo pongo dentro del div con el ngrepeat, ya lo saqué de ahi y parece que funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, en angularjs aun no es posible crear `ng-models` dinamicos en este caso cuando hay un `ng-repeat` lo que te aconsejo (que lo soluciona de muy buena manera es lo siguiente :

Defini un arreglo llamado `models` vacio y cree un arreglo de contactos (ya que no se como los obtienes tu)

```
$scope.model = [];
$scope.contactos = [
    { id: 1, nombre: "Contacto 1", telefono: '' },
    { id: 2, nombre: "Contacto 2", telefono: '' }
];
```

Luego hago un `each` sobre `$scope.contactos` y le asigno valores a `$scope.model`

```
angular.forEach($scope.contactos, function(index, contacto){
    $scope.model[index.id] = "";
});
```

Este codigo crea un indice dentro del arreglo `$scope.models` con las id de tus contactos...

Quedaria algo asi, si imprimes `$scope.model`

```
{1 : '', 2: ''}
```

Cuando dibujas el formulario con el `ng-repeat` seria algo asi :

```
<div ng-repeat="contacto in contactos">
    <p>Nombre : {{contacto.nombre}}</p>
    Telefono : <input type="text" ng-model="model[contacto.id]" placeholder="Ingrese telefono">
</div>
```

Si te fijas, el input de telefono lleva el `ng-model=model[contacto.id]` esto quiere decir, que ahora es independiente un item del `ng-repeat` con otro. Esto te ayudara a validar el telefono que corresponda y no todos, ya que tu antiguamente tenias para todos los `ng-repeat` que se generaban el mismo `ng-model`.

Supongamos que tu obtienes los datos desde una consulta a tu servidor y SI es que el contacto ya tiene un numero de telefono y ese valor viene en la consulta, no cuesta nada setearlo a su modelo, ya que es propio y seria asi :

```
angular.forEach($scope.contactos, function(index, contacto){
    $scope.model[index.id] = index.telefono;
});
```

Te dejo un [codepen](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/gLQaVq) con este mismo ejemplo, para que lo veas, lo que deberias agregar ahora seria la validación que creaste, pero con eso no habria ningun problema.

**EDICION**

Como puedes agregar más de 1 telefono y es un elemento dinamico te recomiendo lo siguiente :

Agrege al objeto contacto un arreglo que se llama telefonos (pueden venir o no, segun corresponda tus datos)

El arreglo `models` ya no es necesario.

```
$scope.contactos = [
       {id:1, nombre : "Contacto 1", telefonos : [{0 : '54565432'}]},
       {id:2, nombre : "Contacto 2", telefonos : [{}]}
];
```

Para listarlos es de la siguiente manera :

```
<div ng-repeat="contacto in contactos">
    <p>Nombre : {{contacto.nombre}}</p>
    Telefono :
    <button ng-click="agregarNumero(contacto)">Agregar numero</button>
    <div ng-repeat="tel in contacto.telefonos">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese telefono" ng-model="tel[$index]">
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="enviar" ng-click="enviar()">
```

Agregue un boton que tiene la funcion `agregarNumero` y le envio por parametro el contacto que corresponde al `ng-repeat` y la funcion hace lo siguiente :

```
$scope.agregarNumero = function(contacto){
    if(contacto.telefonos.length < 4){
      contacto.telefonos.push({});
    }
}
```

Que no hace mas que agregar un objeto vacio al arreglo `telefonos` del contacto sin superar los 4.

Finalmente la funcion `enviar` imprime el arreglo `$scope.contactos`

Si de tas cuenta a medida que agregar, se va agregando un input para ingresar ese telefono

```
$scope.enviar = function(){
    console.log($scope.contactos);
}
```

Debes agregar a

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese telefono" ng-model="tel[$index]">
```

La validación de que tienes.

El codepen tambien esta actualizado

**EDICION 2**

Al intentar validar el regex con `ng-model` en un `ng-repeat` se me hizo imposible por lo que hice lo siguiente :

Cree un `directive` llamado `phone` que basicamente evalua si se cumple el match con el regex que tu me entregaste.

```
var app = angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
var PHONE_REGEXP = /^\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{4}$/;
app.directive('phone', function() {
    return {
        restrice: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            angular.element(element).bind('blur', function() {
                var value = this.value;
                if (PHONE_REGEXP.test(value)) {
                    angular.element(this).next().css('display', 'none');
                    angular.element(this).css('background', 'none');
                } else {
                    angular.element(this).next().css('display', 'block');
                    angular.element(this).css('background', 'red');
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

En la vista hice lo siguiente:

Deje todo dentro del `<form name="form>` le puse el atributo `name=phone` y agrege `data-phone` al input (el `ng-model` sigue igual)

Ademas agregue el siguiente codigo :

```
<span style="display:none;">Por favor ingresa un numero valido.</span>
```

Por defecto oculto

Si te dijas, en el `directive` recibo un elemento que es `angular.element(this)` que vendria siendo el `<input>` en donde el usuario esta escribiendo.. al ocupar `next()` obtengo el siguiente que seria el `<span>` si la validacion con el `regex` es invalida, al elemento le poongo el fondo rojo (solo como ejemplo, tu puedes dar otro color, una clase, etc) y le doy `display:block` al `<span>` que estaba oculto.

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
    <div ng-repeat="contacto in contactos">
        <p>Nombre : {{contacto.nombre}}</p>
        Telefono :
        <button ng-click="agregarNumero(contacto)">Agregar numero</button>
        <div ng-repeat="tel in contacto.telefonos">
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="telefono" data-phone placeholder="Ingrese telefono" ng-model="tel[$index]" />
            <span style="display:none;">Por favor ingresa un numero valido.</span> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="enviar" ng-click="enviar()">
</form>
```

Comment: el problema es que tengo otra estructura, es un solo contacto, y el campo telefonos es un arreglo si le doy en un boton agregar me permite agregar hasta 4 telefonos de un mismo contacto.

Comment: puedes mostrar la estructura?

Comment: acabo de editar...

Comment: @AlbertoRojas actualice

Comment: ya lo probé y no funciona ni en el pen que pusiste.... @sioesi

Comment: Que es lo que no funciona exactamente? @AlbertoRojas

Comment: le puse una validación pattern y si agrego un teléfono correcto en el primer contacto y en el segundo le pongo un telefono incorrecto, muestra el mensaje de error en ambos aunque el primero si es correcto.

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo de esa validacion?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50156/discussion-between-sioesi-and-alberto-rojas).

Comment: @AlbertoRojas puedes volver al chat?

Comment: @AlbertoRojas bien que te haya funcionado, saludos y exito!