# Evitar pasar valores dos veces

Tags: javascript, angularjs

cuando doy clic en el **checkbox** agrega los valores que tengo a otra tabla pero lo que quiero evitar que si da nuevamente click al mismo **checkbox** **que evite agregar nuevamente su valor** ya que ya lo tiene la otra tabla.

**Html donde extraigo los valores**

```
   <tr ng-repeat="vacanteP in vacantesPerCtrl.vacantesLis">                           
        <td class="text-center">{{ vacanteP.nombreVacante }}</td>                            

         <input type="checkbox"
                ng-disabled="vacantesPerCtrl.limiteP"
                ng-click="vacantesPerCtrl.addVacantes(vacanteP, $index)">
         <span class="lever"></span>
         <small>Postular</small>

      </tr>
```

javaScript

```
scope.addVacantes = function(object, index){

 scope.addListaVacantesP.push(
    { operativo:object.nombreProyecto, estado:object.nombreEstado,
      municipio:object.nombreMunicipio, vacante:object.nombreVacante, valor:object.idConfigVacProy }
);
```

}

**Html donde los muestro**

```
<tr ng-repeat="vacantesLista in vacantesPerCtrl.addListaVacantesP">
    <td class="text-center">{{ vacantesLista.operativo }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ vacantesLista.estado }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ vacantesLista.municipio }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ vacantesLista.vacante }}</td>

 </tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al trabajar con angularjs puedes darle a tu checkbox un `ng-model` y un `ng-change`

Como es un checkbox tiene 2 valores por defecto o `true` o `false` y ese valor podemos rescatarlo con el `ng-model`

Con el tag `ng-change` podemos identificar cuando cambia este valor. Seteamos una funcion, algo asi.

```
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="checkModel"
       ng-disabled="vacantesPerCtrl.limiteP"
       ng-change="vacantesPerCtrl.addVacantes(vacanteP, $índex)">
```

Desde el controlador lo siguiente :

```
$scope.addVacantes = funcion(vacanteP, index) {
     if($scope.checkModel){
            guardas en la tabla
     }else {
            //evitas guardarla nuavemente
     }
}
```

**OPCION 2**

Dejas tu codigo tal y como esta. Definir al inicio de tu controlador una variable, por ejemplo `$scope.guardar = true` dentro de tu funcion `addVacantes` pones lo siguiente

```
if($scope.guardar){
      //guardas lo que quieras y cambias el valor de $scope.guardar
      $scope.guardar = false;
}
```

Esto evitara que si haces click denuevo, no entre y no haga nada

**EDICION**

tal como respondi en [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39218/como-validar-un-input-en-angular-para-que-no-muestre-error-en-los-otros-si-se-m/39223#39223) pregunta, Angularjs no soporta aun modelos dinamicos dentro de un `ng-repeat` y por lo tanto debes crearlo. En tu controlador debes recorrer tu arreglo y crear UN modelo unico para cada uno de ellos, tu tiends el campo ID por lo tanto sera facil, ve mi respuesta que tiene un codepen de demostracion y te sera facil lograr lo que quieres. Siempre validando por modelo.

Comment: si funciono solo que se lo aplica a todos mis checkbox y por consecuencia ya no puedo agregar ningún dato mas, ya que uso un ng-repeat lo cual agrega varios checkbox y eso afecta a todos. Saludos..

Comment: Estimado, actualizare mi respuesta @wootsbot

Comment: Cualquier duda me comentas @wootsbot

Comment: estoy en eso, estoy resolviendolo